# IOS - Facebook Like tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Currently creating a facebook like application, for which I need to create a custom UITableviewCell which has label that contains post whose length is dynamic as well as like and comment button. On clicking comment button extra tableview should appear just like in facebook. Can any one help me out with this?

Comment: Did you design the UI in Interface builder like the one you want? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: what you have tried and where you are facing problem?

Comment: Actually I designed a simple cell just like facebook containing post i.e single line post , like and comment button. I am stuck there. Don't know what to do next.

Comment: okay, so next you should get the data that will be displayed in the cell and then you should search for dynamic height management of controls you are using.

Comment: I am done with displaying cell content as well as dynamic height management. Now should i create another custom cell in order to display comments?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a hint,

```
var commentClicked : Bool = false 

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3 //Replace 3 with number of posts
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if commentClicked == false {
        //1 for the post
        return 1
    } else {
        //Replace 2 with number of comments
        return 2
    }
}
```

Define your cellForRowAtIndexPath as you need.
Also a IBAction for your comment button.
Reload tableView on click of this comment button.

Hope this helps.